# Where do screenshots go now that I've installed Ventura?

Tags: software-update, screen-capture, ventura

Until upgrading my operating system to Ventura, screenshots taken with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> went to my Desktop.

Now I can't find them. Does anyone else have this problem? Any idea where they are, or how I can move them back?

MBP 15" 2019 Intel core, OS: 13.0.1 (22A400)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> to display the Screenshot tools UI:

   [image]
2. Click on the Options button to display the submenu where you can choose the Save to location or view the pre-configured location.

Answer (score 11):

Adding this answer for details on the eventual solution after determining details of the real problem.

<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> brought me to the Screenshot application UI and I was able to determine that it goes to the Desktop.

However, right after taking a screenshot using that method, I discovered that the icon appeared on the Desktop and then suddenly disappeared.

Ten minutes later, turns out that the real problem was that Dropbox was immediately snagging and backing up the screenshots without leaving them in place.

Answer (score 5):

When you take a screenshot, it first appears in the bottom right-hand corner of the screen. Then, if you don't do anything, it will auto-save after a few moments to a location of your choosing.

To control the location it saves, open Screenshot.app and click Options. You will see the selected location to save, and can adjust it to Desktop if it's set improperly.

Comment: The simplest way to open the Screenshot app is Cmd/Shift/5, where you will also find other types of screenshot it can make - & also disable the floating thumbnail which prevents you accessing the file until it disappears.

Answer (score 3):

To check the native screenshot tool's preferences from Terminal:

```
defaults read com.apple.screencapture
```

To output only the save destination:

```
defaults read com.apple.screencapture location
```

And to reset everything to defaults:

```
defaults delete com.apple.screencapture
```

Answer (score 0):

You already commented that it was Dropbox that absconded with your screenshots.  I was going to suggest that perhaps there was some automation set up that was moving them quickly.  I have Hazel do this, but after a period of time and only if they remain with the name unchanged.  By default, the screenshots will be saved to your desktop.  Someone mentioned that the screenshot will appear temporarily in the lower right corner before being saved to the location it is going to be saved.  You can turn that feature off in the same Screenshot.app that was also mentioned previously.